# Optional match pattern after wildcard

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-greedy

I am trying to do pattern matching with regex and it seems I can't capture a certain section with an optional section following it, all following a wildcard capture. I'm not sure how to solve it.

Here are two different examples of the possible regex to match

```
MasterChef Junior 3x03 Grandad Gordon! (2015)
Parks and Recreation 7x03 & 7x04 William Henry Harrison (2015)
```

I need to capture the Title (`MasterChef Junior`), the Season (`3`), the episode(`03`) and the Episode Title (`Grandad Gordon!`).

I have created the regex pattern `^(.*) (\d*)x(\d*)\s*(.*) (\(\d*\))$`
which matches the [MasterChef Junior example](https://www.regex101.com/r/uU8sS1/2), but not the [Parks and Recreation example](https://www.regex101.com/r/uU8sS1/1) because of the addition of the second `Season#` and `Episode#`.

I have tried adding an optional match to catch the second `SeasonxEpisode` but it seems the wild card at the start is catching everything and the pattern ignores the optional part (because it doesn't need to use it to match).

[example with optional](https://www.regex101.com/r/uU8sS1/3) `(?:\s*&\s*\d*x\d*)?`

How can I solve this regex problem? Is there a way I can capture the wild card at the start in a non [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) way?

Comment: you mean this https://www.regex101.com/r/uU8sS1/4 ? make the first `.*` as non-greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like i said in my comment, you need to change the first `.*` to `.*?`. Because `.*` is greedy and it matches all the characters as much as possible. Changing it to `.*?`, will do a non-greedy match.

```
^(.*?) (\d*)x(\d*)(?:\s*&\s*\d*x\d*)?\s*(.*) (\(\d*\))$
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/uU8sS1/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*?) (\d*)x(\d*)\s*(.*?) (\(\d*\))$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/59

Just change your first `(.*)` to `(.*?)` make it non greedy to let it capture what you want.